# Why xp_cmdshell exports empty PDF files from database that stored in image datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xp-cmdshell

I have query that extracts PDF files into directory. But for some reason all files are empty (0 KB). 
Column `PDF` stored as `image` datatype. I know its obsolete but I am not the owner of the database. 
Would you suggest any workaround?

```
CREATE TABLE #tblPolicyForms
(
    FormID INT NOT NULL
    ,PDF varbinary(max) NULL
    ,PDF_FIlename VARCHAR(max)
)


INSERT INTO #tblPolicyForms
SELECT  FormID,
        PDF,
        PDF_FileName
FROM    [dbo].[tblPolicyForms]
WHERE   FormID IN (19,20,21,22)
--select * from #tblPolicyForms

DECLARE @FormID varchar(4);
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(200);

DECLARE FormID_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT
    FormID
    ,PDF_FIlename
FROM
  #tblPolicyForms
WHERE FormID IN (19,20,21,22)



OPEN FormID_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor
INTO @FormID, @FileName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000) = 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM #tblPolicyForms " queryout "C:\Users\oserdyuk\Documents\ExportDir\'+@FileName+'" -T -N'
    --print @cmd
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd;

FETCH NEXT FROM FormID_cursor
INTO @FormID, @FileName

END

CLOSE FormID_cursor
DEALLOCATE FormID_cursor
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The thing is BCP is opening another connection to SQL Server, and regular temp tables like your `#tblPolicyForms` are private to the connection. The BCP is probably generating an error which you don't get to see.

Can you change your temp table to a global one? This way the other connection (BCP) will be able to access it. You need to use two pound signs like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ##tblPolicyForms
(
    FormID INT NOT NULL
    ,PDF varbinary(max) NULL
    ,PDF_FIlename VARCHAR(max)
)
```

You also need to change every reference from `#tblPolicyForms` to `##tblPolicyForms` (single to double pounds). Be aware that if the procedure is executed in parallel by different sessions you will receive an error indicating that `##tblPolicyForms` already exists.

Another thing, you are exporting every row into every file, so every file ends up the same size as you have seen. You need a WHERE clause in your BCP like this:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000) = 'BCP "SELECT PDF FROM ##tblPolicyForms WHERE FormID = ''' + @FormID + '''  " queryout "C:\Users\oserdyuk\Documents\ExportDir\'+@FileName+'" -T -N'
```

But even then things might not work properly because bcp will prepend a 8 byte header to your row. Since bcp is an export/import tool it will create a file it can later import back into your database.

Comment: Thanks. The size of each file now is 63 KB which is weird that they are all the same size. But when I try to open it  - the Acrobat Reader gives me an error: " could not open because its either not a supported file type or because file has been damaged"

Comment: I didn't realize, but you are exporting every row to every file. You need a WHERE clause in your BCP. I'll edit the answer above with that information.